Why does my relative href link not work on non-Chromium browsers?
All of my <a> tags only work on desktop browsers, but not on mobile.
Example:
<a href="/events">
  Events
</a>

When I tap on them, it navigates me to <domain>events/, instead of <domain>/events. Even if I manually type <domain>/events in my browser, it navigates to <domain>events/.
I have tested this on Arc for iOS, Google Chrome for iOS, Firefox for Windows 11, Google Chrome for Windows 11, and Microsoft Edge for Windows 11. The <a> tags only work as-expected for the Chromium browsers (Edge and Chrome).
You can see for yourself on my website. Click on any of the nav bar items.
For reference, I am deploying this website on a VM via Apache httpd. I am very new to using Apache. The website is made using Astro.js, which I used to generate a dist, and copied the files into /var/www/http, which is running the website above. You can view the website's code here.
UPDATE: I can correctly navigate to <domain>/events/index.html. This means that the browser can correctly redirect /events to the index.html file, but on mobile, it cannot

FYI, your website's nav bar also displays the erroneous behavior of linking to <domain>events/ on Firefox 130.0.1 (latest version) on Windows 11, but works fine on Google Chrome and other chromium-based browsers.

Is it possible you have a .htaccess file that is doing an improper rewrite?

It's working as I'd expect it to. Apache is doing a 301 redirect to add a / to the end of the dir name. You don't need HTML to demonstrate this, just type the link directly into the URL bar and it adds the /. I don't know why Chrome is not displaying it.
